# Помогите с лямбда выражением для сортировки

Tags: c++, сортировка, c++11, лямбда-выражение

Проблема с лямбда функцией, вроде написал сортировку вектора по остаткам по возрастанию, так, чтобы числа с одинаковыми остатками выводились по возрастанию но она не работают, я ещё не совсем разбираюсь в сортировка по лямбда выражениям подскажите где накосячил плиз.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

int main(){
    ll n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<ll> V(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> V[i];
    sort(V.begin(), V.end(), [&k](ll a, ll b)
    {
        return (a % k < b % k);
    });

    sort(V.begin(), V.end(), [&k](ll a, ll b)
    {
        return (a % k == b % k && a < b);
    });
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << V[i] << " ";
```

Comment: Что значит не работает? Добавьте детальное описание того как должна работать сортировка, сейчас непонятно, что делать с числами у которых разные остатки. И было бы хорошо иметь пример результата такой сортировки

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, что Вы накрутили, то мне кажется, Вам нужно объединить эти две лямбды, и выполнять сортировку один раз. Сейчас у Вас, как понимаю, вторая сортировка портит первую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы использовал

```
sort(V.begin(), V.end(), [k](ll a, ll b)
     {
         return (a%k == b%k) ? a < b : a%k < b%k;
     }
);
```

По-моему, то, что надо: https://ideone.com/OfIE0t